# Proving that the formula is not well-formed-formula

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Right now I am studying logic, and a bit confused on how to prove that some formula is not a well-formed formula. Here is my (or my course's) definition of well formed formula:

Suppose that $P$ is a set of proposition, and suppose that alphabet of the string is $P \cup C \cup D$ where $D=\{'(', ')'\}$ is the set containing close parentheses and open parentheses symbols.  where $C := \{\neg, \vee, \wedge\}$ . The formula is well-formed if it is in the "smallest" set (i.e. intersections over every WFF which are subset of the universe / set of the every possible strings) of closed sets (i.e. closed under conjunction, negation, disjunction) which are constructed as follows:

1. P $\subset WFF$
2. If $\phi, \psi$ is WFF then $(\phi \vee \psi) \in WFF$
3. If $\phi, \psi$ is WFF then $(\phi \wedge \psi) \in WFF$
4. If $\phi \in WFF$ then $(\neg\phi) \in WFF$

Based on this definition, I want to prove that empty string, and invalid formulas like $p\neg$ are not WFF. How could I formally prove this although intuitively it is so correct. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Yes...This is the exact definition provided by the prof, and our homework (later part of the homework) is to prove the equivalence of different constructions of the well-formed formula

Comment: I suspect based upon this phrase "of closed sets (i.e. closed under conjunction, negation, disjunction)", my proof is a bit simplistic for your course, but maybe someone else can benefit.

Comment: Note that the empty string is not a member of P.  In other words, it is not a proposition.  Nor does it have a '∨', '∧', or '¬' symbol in it.  Consequently, it is not a WFF, since there does not exist any construction of it according to the formation rules.  Note also, that every wff which is not a member of P, starts with a '(' and ends with a ')'.  ' p¬' does not.   OR if the question asks about '(p¬)' as a wff.... the definition implies for classes or forms of WFFs by their primary connective, '∧', '∨', or '¬'.  Then show that '(p¬)' doesn't have any primary connective.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question.

The empty string, $\lambda \notin P$
Every element of P has length of at least 1.
All other WFF's are constructed from elements of P or combinations of P, C or D, or other WFF's.  These combinations adds length to the WFF.
The length of every WFF is at least 1.
However, $\lambda$ has length zero and therefore not a WFF.

If you need something more formal, the next step up would be a proof by recursive or structural induction.  This is a variation of natural induction, but applies to recursively defined sets.

For the second example, either $p\neg$ or $(p\neg )$, try something similar, except you may need to exhaust all the possibilities of length 1, 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: A comment on your last paragraph. Surely it is trivial to prove that there are no wffs of length $2$? (or $3$ for that matter)

Comment: Ummm, how about $\neg p$?
Isn't this a WFF?
and $p \vee q$, $p \wedge q$ are also WFF's.

Comment: No! the rules say that $(\lnot p)$ (of length $4$)  is a WFF. The parentheses are part of the alphabet and you can't just remove them.

Comment: Oops, it appears I was blind to the "(" and ")" in the rules.  I edited the paragraph accordingly.

Comment: But you have now made it about $(p\lnot)$ and not about $p\lnot$ as the OP asks. These details really matter.

Comment: Ok, well then, technically, $\neg p$ is not allowed in this language.  Proving neither is in this definition of WFF's is about the same proof.

Comment: "technically" ???!!!!!! The whole question is about the nitty-gritty technicalities: continued hand-waving just confuses the issue.

Comment: With all due respect, Doug Sponwood's comment above is far more fruitful/beneficial than this line of conversation.